# JDBC connect to MSSQL named instance with non-standard port

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, jira, windows-server-2008-r2

Hello guys I'm working on a project and I'm trying to connect [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) to a MSSQL aliased or named instance. Checkout [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3689846/Using-Non-Standard-Port-for-SQL-Server.htm) if you don't know what i'm talking about.

Under this setup, for example, when you want to connect to a specific DB server, let's say using SQL Studio, you have to use "servername,port" as in the mssql server alias configuration, that reflects the DB instance.

What would be the connection string to use under this circunstances?

I've [read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/03/03/running-sql-server-default-instance-on-a-non-default-or-non-standard-tcp-port-tips-for-making-application-connectivity-work.aspx) about issues with this kind of setup as I'm using the JDBC driver (JIRA uses it). You can try with [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) for testing this, as it uses the same driver.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server JDBC you either connect to the named instance or to a specific port. If you specify both named instance and port, it will ignore the instance name.

If you want to connect to a named instance which is not running on the default port, you will need to have the **SQL Server Browser** service running on the server, this allows the JDBC driver to lookup the right port based on the instance name. I believe this service by default is disabled.